# invalid utf-8 sequence when using includegraphics with LuaTeX on MacOS 14.4

Tags: graphics, luatex, includegraphics, dvi-mode

When compiling a document using LuaTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023/Homebrew)

`dvilualatex --halt-on-error --interaction=nonstopmode --synctex=-1 C3.tex`

and containing

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Logo.pdf}
%     \caption{Caption here}
%     \label{fig:logo}
\end{figure}
```

I receive the following error

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
<read 0> %
    ���������^^@
l.44 ...ncludegraphics[scale=0.5]
```

This error occurs regardless of path or filename. it only occurs on the includegraphics line. It also happens with `.jpg` files as well. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does it occur on a specific line only? Or does it always occur on every `\includegraphics` line? Did you copy and paste your sample code directly from your tex file, or did you retype it? Copying what you've shown above does not show any weird UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: What happens if you omit the filename extension (pdf, jpg, etc)? Incidentally, like @WillieWong, I am unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered when I make your code snippet minimally compilable by prefixing `\documentclass{article} \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} \begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}` to it and then running the `dvilualatex` instruction. (I use MacTeX2023.)

Comment: why dvilualtex (which is hardly ever used)? in particular which dvi driver do you use, latex will default to dvips here but if you are using xdvipdfmx you should use that option to graphicx (it may still not work but it would affect the place where any fix is made)  in particular dvips can't include pdf so the only improvement could be a better error message but with dvipdfmx then it could (perhaps) be made to work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because that is what is used by the LaTeX Previewer VS Code extension. it offers almost instantaneous preview of file edits, if I could get images working.

Comment: really? which dvi driver does it use? (it's relatively recently that any dvi driver at all could cope with the dvi files from luatex)

Comment: @DavidP https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjpvs.latex-previewer  hmmm and watching the screenshots flash past they show graphicx with no options so it is the default dvips you should use (and eps figures)

Comment: try `example-image.eps`

Comment: Did you get this to work? I was intruigued enough to install this extension and as you say it does use dvilualatex and does work and does not show images. The flashing self advert on the extension home page clearly shows images working but I tried various things and they didn't work for me.  If you make contact with the developer and find the magic, please post here and ping me and I'll update the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the examples I tried dvilualatex works with pdf files if you use the dvipdfmx dvi driver

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `dvisvgm` option also works.

The problem with the default `dvips` option is that it defaults unknown extensions to `eps` handling and that is doomed to fail, although it would be better to have a better error.

We could modify `dvips.def` so `.pdf` was not an unknown extension, but known but with no rule, then it would behave like

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{pdf}{}{}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
\end{document}
```

which gives much better error messages:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in example-image.pdf (no size s
pecified).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
                                      
? 

! LaTeX Error: Can not include graphics of type: pdf.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \includegraphics{example-image.pdf}
                                      
?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Adding \usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx} resolved the error. I am not seeing any images displayed however, even when using your example, nor with .png, .jpg images.

Comment: @DavidP which dvi driver are you using? if I use `[dvipdfmx]` option and `dvipdfmx` program to convert the dvi to pdf I get the output shown. Naturally if you use `[dvipdfmx]` option then use `dvips` to convert the dvi file, it will not work.

Comment: I must confess that I am not too knowlagable about this DVI latex situation. I am using your above suggestion of `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`, and the original dvilualatex command. I have given up, and switched to pdflatex. too bad, because the dvi VS code integration has great potential!

Comment: the question is how is the dvi being displayed, is it using a native dvi viewer (I did not think there was any that would work with dviluatex) or is it converting to pdf and showing the pdf, in which case the `[...]` option should tell latex which converter is being used. so `[dvipdfmx]` if the dvipdfmx program is being used, not otherwise. @DavidP

Comment: answering my own comment, the vscode extension implements a native canvas dvi previewer within vscode, and requires dvilualatex